# Prove that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-x)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+x)=\frac{\pi}{\cos\pi x}$

Tags: gamma-function

I have to prove this equality $$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-x)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+x)=\frac{\pi}{\cos\pi x}$$
I assume, since both Gamma's have $\frac12$ as part of their argument, I'll have to use the fact that $\Gamma(\frac12)=\sqrt\pi$ I just don't know how. I also thought of using $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}$.

Comment: Your last sentence is the thing to do: just a $\frac12$ shift!

Comment: Oh my, It's so obvious. How could I not see this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It happens to me rather often as well...

Comment: This will help you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159079/what-is-gamma1-2-n-gamma1-2n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an answer here for the sake of closing the question.

Since
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x},$$
it follows that
$$\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}+x)=\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)\Gamma(1-(\tfrac{1}{2}-x))=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)}=\frac{\pi}{\cos\pi x},$$
which is the desired solution.